# Should I indexing the `id` field as NumericField?

Tags: java, lucene

the `id` filed is a Integer(from 1 to Integer.MAX_VALUE,unique),

I don't need range searches by `id` field,

only use id(a number) to search(get) and sort against the `id` field.

should I choice NumericField type?

if so how do I set `precision step` parameter?

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, NumericField would work perfectly for your ID field. If you want to be able to sort and filter but don't need range queries, just [use a precision step of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html#precisionStepDesc).